# how to add summed values together with joins in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables

table 1 and table 2  are both associated to table 3 with "ItemId" foreign key

I want to write a query which will return some statistical data based on these tables

table 3 provides the name column, the rest is from the other two

```
SELECT t1.ItemId, name, currentQuantity, previousQuantity, currentValue, previousValue
FROM (
  SELECT ItemId, SUM(quantity) as currentQuantity, SUM(quantity * purchaseNetPrice) AS currentValue
  FROM table_1
  GROUP BY ItemId
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT ItemId, SUM(quantity) as previousQuantity, SUM(quantity * purchaseNetPrice) AS previousValue
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY ItemId
) AS t2 ON t1.ItemId = t2.ItemId
INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_1.ItemId = table_3.ItemId
```

This will output

```
ItemId | name |  currentQuantity  | previousQuantity| currentValue | previousValue
-------+------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------
 1     |ITEM1 | 4500              | 27000           | 523000       | 3240000       |
 2     |ITEM2 | 5800              | 15000           | 386000       | 2250000       |
```

Which is fine at this point, but I also want to calculate the quantity and value difference so

```
ItemId | name |  currentQuantity  | previousQuantity| currentValue | previousValue | qDiff | valDiff
-------+------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------
 1     |ITEM1 | 4500              | 27000           | 523000       | 3240000       | diff  | diff
 2     |ITEM2 | 5800              | 15000           | 386000       | 2250000       | diff  | diff
```

with the following logic:

quantity difference -> currentQuantity - previousQuantity

value difference ->  currentValue - previousValue

Where do I put this in a single query?

Comment: Woudl not `SELECT t1.ItemId, .....,   currentQuantity - previousQuantity as qDiff, currentValue - previousValue as valDiff FROM (....`  do?

Comment: Hm..that's interesting. It works, for some reason when I previously tried it, I got an error saying the column does not exists.

Comment: @Michal you should add it as an answer :) (since it works for the OP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the additional columns in the outer `SELECT` and aliasing those with `AS` does the job:

```
SELECT t1.ItemId, 
       name, 
       currentQuantity, 
       previousQuantity, 
       currentValue, 
       previousValue, 
       currentQuantity - previousQuantity as qDiff, 
       currentValue - previousValue as valDiff 
FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You got most of it right. I would right it using subquery factoring (WITH AS) for clean code.

```
WITH t1_summary as
(
  SELECT ItemId, SUM(quantity) as currentQuantity, SUM(quantity * purchaseNetPrice) AS currentValue
  FROM table_1
  GROUP BY ItemId
),
t2_summary as (SELECT ItemId, SUM(quantity) as previousQuantity, SUM(quantity * purchaseNetPrice) AS previousValue
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY ItemId
) 
SELECT t3.ItemId, name, currentQuantity, previousQuantity, currentValue, previousValue, currentQuantity - previousQuantity as quantity_difference, currentValue - previousValue as value_difference
from t3,t1_summary,t2_summary
where t1_summary.ItemId = t3.ItemId
and t2_summary.ItemId = t3.ItemId
```